# Hassle-free js file merging

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I like the approach used by https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer/tree/master for merging js files. But it seems it lakes a watch mechanism. Is it any other similar tool with watch ability?

How can I use PHPStorm features to watch js files and merge all js files?

```
//main.js
/*
@depend x.js
*/

//x.js
var x=3;
```

The problem is that PHPstorms's watcher runs on `x.js` and produces `x.min.js`, while I need `main.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Juicer, but set it up as a file watcher in PHPStorm so that it will run each time you edit your js file. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/file-watchers.html for more information

Smth like:

```
File Type: javascript files
Program: C:\Ruby193\bin\juicer.bat
Arguments: merge $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js
Working Directory: $FileDir$
Output Paths: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js
```

Comment: Beside that do you know how I can prevent minification? I only need merging during development. Juicer seems so slow on my system.

Comment: well, you can modify the -o parameter accordingly - use -o main.min.js instead of -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js. Output paths has to be changed too

Comment: and I have no idea how to avoid minification - actually I haven't heard of juicer before reading your post

Comment: I know that this is an old post but, for reference, you can stop minification in Juicer by adding
`--minifyer ""`
To the end of the command.